# Python 3 types, custom variadic generic type with arbitrary number of contained types, how?

Tags: python-3.x, types, typing, variadic

The class `typing.Tuple` can be used as with arbitrary number of type arguments, like `Tuple[int, str, MyClass]` or `Tuple[str, float]`. How do I implement my own class that can be used like that? I understand how to inherit from `typing.Generic`. The following code demonstrates this.

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic


T = TypeVar("T")


class Thing(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, value: T):
        self.value = value


def f(thing: Thing[int]):
    print(thing.value)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Thing("WTF")
    f(t)
```

The above code would work but the type checker (in my case PyCharm) would catch the fact that `t` should be of type `Thing[int]` and not `Thing[str]`. That's all fine, but how do I make the class `Thing` support arbitrary number of type arguments, like `Tuple` does?

Comment: See https://github.com/python/typing/issues/193

Comment: Thanks @StephaneBersier. I did realise after a while that it's impossible in Python.

Comment: With [PEP 646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) coming to Python 3.11, variadic generics may become possible through `TypeVarTuple`.

Answer (score 0):

Like @metatoaster said in their comment, this is possible using [`TypeVarTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVarTuple), available in `typing` from 3.11 onwards, and `typing_extensions` otherwise:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVarTuple

Ts = TypeVarTuple("Ts")


class Thing(Generic[*Ts]):
    def __init__(self, *value: *Ts):
        self.value = value


def f(thing: Thing[int]):
    print(thing.value)


t = Thing("WTF")  # Type of "t" is "Thing[str]"
f(t)  # error: Type parameter "Ts@Thing" is invariant, but "*tuple[str]" is not the same as "*tuple[int]"
```

Answer (score -4):

- In your example, `t` is of type `Thing`, not `Thing[str]`. So this object accepts anything for `T`.
- You can parametrize it like this : `t2 = Thing[str]("WTF")`
- now, for your question, I think you want to use [typing.Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) like this: `t3=Thing[Union[str,int,float]]("WTF")`

By the way, you can check the type of generics by using get_generic_type() from [typing_inspect](https://github.com/ilevkivskyi/typing_inspect)

```
>>> get_generic_type(t)
__main__.Thing
>>> get_generic_type(t2)
__main__.Thing[str]
>>> get_generic_type(t3)
__main__.Thing[typing.Union[str, int, float]]
```