# Variable number of types of Generic

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing

I'm struggling with a case where I would like to specify that a class inheriting from `typing.Generic` can have various number of types. See a following simple example:

```
from typing import *

T = TypeVar('T')

class C(Generic[T]):
    data: Tuple[int, T]

c = C[str]()
c.data = 4, '4'
```

This case works fine, but allows `data` to be only pairs (tuples of two). I would like to write `C` in such a way that would support tuples of any length and any type, where the first element is `int` -- provided that the types are specified. In particular I want a structure that would allow for following manipulation (not necessarily in this syntax):

```
c1 = C[str]()
c1.data = 1, '1'   # should work
c1.data = 1, '1', '1'  # should report an error

c2 = C[str, float]()
c2.data = 1, '1', 1.0  # should work
c2.data = 1, '1'  # should report an error
c2.data = 1, '1', '1'  # should report an error
```

Is there any way to get described behavior from python / mypy?

Comment: No. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/46487583/1904146